# Accessing Private keys from certificate deployed to windows azure

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to access the private key of a certificate I uploded to Windows azure do do decryption. I used a code similar to this post: [Using DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2 with Azure - Reading Certificate - difficulty extracting keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064554/using-dotnetopenauth-oauth-2-with-azure-reading-certificate-difficulty-extra). Andrew Arnott provided an answer to what post referencing this link: https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/issues/16. However I cannot access it so I am not sure what is the solution. Please help.

Essentially when try to cast the private key of a certificate as a RSACryptoProvider. I get nothing:
Dim provider As RSACryptoServiceProvider = DirectCast(certificate.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)

That is provider is assigned nothing. The code works perfectly outside of Azure.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/08/10/new-windows-azure-security-overview-white-paper-now-available.aspx) blog post it not possible to extract private keys of the certificates deployed to a Azure role.

They are marked as not exportable by the GA (guest agent - A Windows Azure-provided agent that runs within the Guest VM and provides services like installation of certificates and private keys) at the time of instance creation.

From the MS white paper:

> 2.1.1.4 Certificate and Private Key Management
>
> To lower the risk of exposing certificates and private keys to developers and administrators, they
> are installed via a separate mechanism than the code that uses them. Certificates and private
> keys are uploaded via SMAPI or the Windows Azure Portal as PKCS12 (PFX) files protected in
> transit by SSL. Those PKCS12 files may be password protected, but if so, the password must be
> included in the same message. SMAPI removes the password protection (if necessary) and
> encrypts the entire PKCS12 blob using SMAPI’s public key and stores it in a secret store on the
> FC, along with a short certificate name and the public key as metadata.
> The configuration data associated with any role within the same subscription specifies the
> certificates that should be made available to the role. When a role is instantiated on a VM, the
> FC retrieves the appropriate certificate, decrypts the PKCS12 blob, re-encrypts it using the FA’s
> public transport key, and sends it to the FA on the node. The FA on the node sends it to the GA
> in the VM that is instantiating the role, and then the GA decrypts it and installs it in the
> operating system certificate store with a flag indicating that the private key can be used but not
> exported. After installation, all temporary copies of the certificates and keys are destroyed; if
> reinstallation is required, the certificates must be repackaged by the FC.

Comment: Note that exporting the key is not the same as using it. You should still be able to use it; that's in fact the whole purpose of non-exportable keys.

Answer (score 0):

Is your service running with Administrator privileges? By default, your service runs in Full trust with limited privileges.
To change it, you need to define  in your Service Definition file (.csdef). Here's the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx#Runtime

Comment: I added this entry to my service definition <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />. I even added this attribute to the certificate tag: permissionLevel="limitedOrElevated". Neither worked.